# How to move a rectangle in SDL2 using C

Tags: c, events, sdl-2

I'm unable to move the rectangle I made in the program. There is no error message in the compiler when I run the program. Can you please tell me what I missed out in the keyboard event. Other event that I assigned to the window works fine. Instead of writing instructions down can you please show me the solution. I have been on this forever. Thanks

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Window *o;
    SDL_Renderer *r;
    SDL_Event e;
    SDL_Rect q;
    int i =1;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    o = SDL_CreateWindow("Game test",
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                            1024,
                            800,
                            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    r = SDL_CreateRenderer(o, -1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    while(i)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) !=0)
        {
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                i=0;
            else if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                switch(e.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                case SDLK_q:
                    i=0;
                break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    q.y -=10;
                break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    q.y +=10;
                break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    q.x +=10;
                break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    q.x -=10;
                break;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r,0,0,255,255);
        SDL_RenderClear(r);
        // Creating the rectangle
        q.x=475;
        q.y=700;
        q.h=50;
        q.w=50;

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r,0,0,0,255);

        SDL_RenderFillRect(r,&q);

        SDL_RenderPresent(r);
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(o);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(r);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize the rectangle object:

```
SDL_Rect q;
```

before potentially modifying its values in the event loop, which will result in undefined behavior:

```
case SDLK_UP:
    q.y -=10;
break;
```

Then any change made to the object is invalidated when you set constant values to it:

```
q.x=475;
q.y=700;
q.h=50;
q.w=50;
```

So the solution is clear, set the constant values to the object only when you define it.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use struct??

Comment: @user5771881 There was a typo in the answer, maybe that confused you.

Comment: I don't understand by initializing the rectangle object? Can you insert you solution to my code so I can see what you mean.....

Comment: @user5771881 You have to set some values to the rectangle before you use it.

Comment: Are you talking about this: a =475, b=700                                           q.x=a; q.y=b; since a and b variables can be altered would the rectangle move?

Comment: @user5771881 I think you need to read a book or a tutorial about C.

Comment: @user5771881 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Hey, I read the tutorial on the webpage you showed me and I solved it. Thanks for being patient with me. How can I give you points?

Comment: @user5771881 Great. If you found my answer to be helpful, please accept it (The green checkmark next to the answer on the left side), or upvote it.